# Getting a directory tree with Jabaco?

Tags: java, directory-tree, jabaco

Given that [Jabaco](http://www.jabaco.org/) is VB-alike on the surface but Java underneath, can any suggest how to get a directory tree? I think it's got something to do with DirSearch() but as I have no background in Java, I can't think how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jabaco folk and I are [getting there](http://www.jabaco.org/board/p1460-what-the-jabaco-equiv-for-dir-and-getattr.html#post1460)

Answer (score 0):

If it's VB on the outside, then surely the answer is to look for ways to get a directory tree listing in VB?

I googled for "[visual basic get directory tree](http://www.google.com/search?q=visual+basic+get+directory+tree)" and the second result had some VB code that looked reasonable.